# Insertion function into AVL tree won't insert

Tags: c, nodes, avl-tree

I am working on an avl tree with strings as keys. The print statements indicate that the insert is happening but in the testing function it reports that the left and right nodes of the root remain null.

Here is my avl tree code:

```
#include "AVLAdt.h"

void printVal(node * toPrint){
    printf("\n node value: %s\n", toPrint->nodeValue);
}

node * search(node * root, char * searchVal){
    if(isExternal(root) == 1) return NULL;
    if(strcmp(searchVal,root->nodeValue)<0){
        return(search(root->leftNode,searchVal));
    }
    else if(strcmp(searchVal,root->nodeValue)==0){
        return(root);
    }
    else {
        return(search(root->rightNode,searchVal));
    }
}



/*initialize a node*/   
node * initNode(char * toAdd){
    node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(newNode->nodeValue, toAdd);
    newNode->leftNode = NULL;
    newNode->rightNode = NULL;
    newNode->height = 1;
    return newNode;
}



/*function to insert a new node into tree and rebalance if necessary*/
node * insert(node * root, char * newValue){


    if(root == NULL){
        printf("\n Inserting %s. \n", newValue);
        return(initNode(newValue));

    }
    else{

        if(strcmp(newValue,root->nodeValue)<0){
            printf("go left");
            insert(root->leftNode, newValue);
        }
        else if(strcmp(newValue,root->nodeValue)>0){
            printf("go to right node of %s", root->nodeValue);
            insert(root->rightNode, newValue);
        }
        else{
            root->count++;
            return (root);
        }
    }
```

Testing program:

```
#include "AVLAdt.h"

int main(){


    node * root = NULL;

    char * testString = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    strcpy(testString, "aa");

    char * testString1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    strcpy(testString1, "bb");


    printf("does it try to insert?");

    root = insert(root, testString);
    root = insert(root, testString1);

    printVal(root);

    if(getRight(root) == NULL) printf("right is null");
    else{

        printf("right is");
        printVal(getRight(root));
    }

    if(getLeft(root) == NULL) printf("left is null");
    else{

        printf("left is");
        printVal(getRight(root));
    }



    return(0);
}
```

The code returns that both left and right nodes of "aa" are null. Why is this?

Comment: Pay close attention to the return value of your `insert` function. Do you think that may be important when you call `insert(root->leftNode, newValue)` and `insert(root->rightNode, newValue);` both of which currently ignore the result ?

Comment: Thank you for telling me where to look without exactly giving me the answer, it still took me a minute haha. I'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around recursive functions.

Comment: No worries. Recursion is a fickle thing when you first come to it. Remember the call stack and/or the return value is usually where things are "stored" during the descent, making them recoverable later on the way out. Best of luck.

Comment: So did you try proposed changes (see answer below) and did they work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In the `search()` function, not sure why you do

```
if(isExternal(root) == 1) return NULL;
```

If the `node` is external, i.e. doesn't have any leaves, you'd still want to compare its `nodeValue` to the `searchVal` and return `root` in case of match.

In `initNode()` function, next-to-the-last line should be

```
newNode->count = 1;
```

instead of

```
newNode->height = 1;
```

Also, it seems to me that in the `insert()` function, `initNode()`'s return value should be assigned to `root` to store the pointer to the newly added `node` in the tree, i.e. you should have:

```
return root = initNode(newValue);
```

instead of

```
return(initNode(newValue));
```

(you also don't have to put return value in parenthesis by the way).

WhozCraig has already pointed out issue with the return values of recursive `insert()` calls.